# codename one List scroll to the selected item

Tags: codenameone

I want to display a list of names on the screen and a vertical alphabet scroll bar on the right side of it...similar to the contact list application in Android. 
So when I click a letter from alphabet scroll bar, all the names starting with that letter should appear at the top of the screen.

[List of names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zSdZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is what fixed lead section mode does. It fixes the selection in one place so the rest of the list moves around it. This is quite common in non-touch UI's for mobile phones but not so much for newer devices so this feature isn't mentioned in the developer guide or used anywhere in our samples...

Furthermore, please notice that we no longer recommend using `List` as explained in the [section covering it in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html#_list_multilist_renderers_models). It's an advanced and complex component that won't deliver advantages for most common use cases.

Comment: Thanks Shai. Can you please let me know how can I implement the scrolling feature (as explained in my question) in List or using other component if not List?

Comment: I don't understand what type of UI you are trying to achieve if you have a sample of such a UI I might be able to help

Comment: I don't need the sample code, I need an example of the UI you are trying to achieve in screenshots/app samples. If I don't understand the goal from the description, I can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: FYI when you edit the answer you need to post a comment or I won't get a notification of that edit. There are many strategies to do this. You don't actually need a list. I would use a box layout Y containing your entries and place it in a layered layout with another container that has a border layout. In its east side I would put another box layout Y and place the alphabet within it. When a user presses a button in the alphabet just loop the components in the original Box Y and find the one matching the letter and call `requestFocus()`.

Comment: Thanks Shai. I used scrollRectToVisible to display selected item on the top.